# Lumia 1020 automatically adding an IDD prefix

Tags: nokia-lumia-1020

My Nokia Lumia 1020 automatically adds the IDD prefix +44 when I dial certain numbers.

For example; when I dial 85236500, the number +4485236500 comes up on the screen as the number my phone is dialling.

I can't control this. It does it automatically and there's no way I can get it to dial the number required.

How can I stop it doing this, and dial the number I want to dial?

The problem only seems to occur when I dial numbers beginning with "8"

Comment: Is international assist on? Phone -> settings -> international assist.

Comment: Where are you and what is your locale set to?

Answer (score 3):

Seems your **International Assist** is turned on. You can turn it off:

1. Open the **Phone** app
2. Select **Settings** in the app bar
3. *Turn off* **International Assist**

Answer (score 1):

Windows phone comes in with a handy feature which will help you out here.

- Navigate to settings.
- Swipe right to applications.
- Tap on phone.
- Turn on “International assist”.

Missing + before the country code and calling your based out country will be automatically rectified using this feature.

My phone was prefixing the digit 1 before each number starting with 8, the above help to solve my problem