# International Assist in Microsoft Lumia 950?

Tags: lumia-950

How to "turn off" International Assist option in Microsoft Lumia 950?

Comment: This question already has an answer here [Why does my phone keep adding an extra zero when I voice dial a number?](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/12768/why-does-my-phone-keep-adding-an-extra-zero-when-i-voice-dial-a-number)

Answer (score 1):

Settings -> System -> Phone -> international assist (on/off)